# How to store methods with a generic return type in a collection?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

So, my goal is to have a class (ProviderManager) that you can ask to return an object by type like this:

```
var a = ProviderManager.GetObject<ObjA>();
```

The ProviderManager holds a dictionary that maps types to delegates, those delegates are classes that create objects of a concrete type (Provider>. When GetObject is called, the ProviderManager calls the function that creates the concrete object.
The providers are implemented in a separate project.

#### Provider Manager

```
public class ProviderManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action> _ProviderMapping = new Dictionary<Type, Action>();

    public void Register<T>(Type objType, IProvider<T> provider)
    {
        _ProviderMapping.Add(objType, provider.GetObject());
    }

    public T GetObject<T>()
    {
        _ProviderMapping.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key == typeof(T)).Value();
    }
}
```

#### Provider Interface

```
public interface IProvider<T>
{
    void Register();
    T GetObject();
}
```

#### Sample Provider

```
public class ProviderForA : IProvider<ObjA>
{
    private ProviderManager _Manager;

    public ProviderForA(ProviderManager manager)
    {
        _Manager = manager;
    }

    public void Register()
    {
        _Manager.Register(typeof(ObjA), this);
    }

    public ObjA GetObject()
    {
        return new ObjA();
    }
}
```

The issue is, that _ProviderMapping.Add(objType, **provider.GetObject()**); causes the error "cannot convert T to Sytem.Action". Adding a void function works, so I guess it is connected to the return value. I tried also to add a generic return type to Action but this also does not work.

The goal is, that a project (provider module) is responible for creating objects, it registers a class that implements the provider interface at the provider manager (manager module). The user code then asks the manager module for an object of a concrete type. The manager forwards the call to the provider that returns the actual object.

Comment: `_ProviderMapping.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key == typeof(T)).Value();` -- doing an O(n) lookup through a dictionary which provides O(1) lookup seems rather silly. Why not do a normal lookup?

Comment: Your `_ProviderMapping` dictionary contains Actions. Actions don't return a value. Did you mean for it to contain `Func<object>`s perhaps?

Comment: Use dictionary indexer to get a value by key

Comment: @canton7 yes, normal lookup would be better.

I tried to add a return type, but with object it says "wrong return type", I tried also Func<T> but it still says "wrong return type".

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
public class ProviderManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> _providerMapping =
        new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>();

    public void Register<T>(IProvider<T> provider)
    {
        _providerMapping .Add(typeof(T), () => provider.GetObject());
    }

    public T GetObject<T>()
    {
        if (!_providerMapping.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var factory))
            throw ...
        return (T)factory();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public void Register()
{
    _Manager.Register(this);
}
```

We have a dictionary full of lots of delegates which return different types. We have to use the common type among these, which is `object`, and store `Func<object>`s in our dictionary. We then cast the `object` to the appropriate `T` in `GetObject<T>()`.